# Check Required Field Validators using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have multiple div containers with multiple asp.net required field validators. I want to show the summary report with Div Id.

like "Some fields are blank inside 'Div1'.
 "Some fields are blank inside 'Div2'.

"Is it's possible through Jquery" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flag=true;
var summary=""
$('#div1 input:not([type=checkbox])').each(
    function(){
       if (this.value==""){
         flag=false
       }
    }
);
if(flag){
   summary+="Some fields are blank inside div1"
}
```

Repeat this for every div (manually, or via a for loop).

Basically, within each div, I'm picking up all of the input fields, and checking if they are empty one by one. I'm excluding checkboxes since an unticked checkbox doesn't mean "empty"

Comment: Thanks,for your reply. But this code will work for Textbox. My form contains different validation controls like Required Field Validator, Regula Expression Validator etc. and I am using css class "validator" for every validation contorl.